# How to find the execution time of the python unit test by timeit function

Tags: python, selenium, unit-testing, timeit

Here is the code snippet.
Is this is the correct way of calling the test method inside the timeit?
The script is executing but i am not seeing the timestamp for the test_SignIn()
please help me out of this issue.

```py
if __name__== "__main__":
 import timeit  unittest.main(testRunner=HtmlTestRunner.HTMLTestRunner(output='C:\\Users\\Swarna\\PycharmProjects\\PersonalLoanUnitTest_POMBasedProject\\Reports'))
    print("Sign_In")
    print(timeit.timeit("test_SignIn()", setup="from __main__ import test_SignIn"))

    def test_SignIn(self):
        SIP = SignInpage(self.driver)
        SIP.ClickSignInLink()
        rows = XLUtils.getRowCount(self.signInpath, 'Sheet1')
        for r in range(2, rows + 1):
            mobileno = XLUtils.readData(self.signInpath, 'Sheet1', r, 1)
            password = XLUtils.readData(self.signInpath, 'Sheet1', r, 2)
            SIP.setMobileNumber(mobileno)
            SIP.setPassword(password)
            SIP.ClickSignInButton()
            UserName = SIP.getUserName()
```